# Post error in Ajax calling in asp.net project

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

[image]

I am working on one project in asp.net webforms. There is one form in modal popup I want to post that form. But in button click even I didn't get vaule value of textbox and dropdownlist. So I decided to use Ajax call but getting this issue.

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
    $("[id*=btnSave]").bind("click", function () {
        debugger;
        var dd = {};
        dd.AttendedBy = $("[id*=AttendByTb]").val();
        dd.HandeledBy = $("[id*=HandleByTb]").val();
        dd.ClosedBy = $("[id*=CloseByTb]").val();
        dd.ActionTaken = $("[id*=ActionDdl] option:selected").val();
        dd.SolutionGiven = $("[id*=SolutionDdl] option:selected").val();
        var ticket = JSON.stringify(dd);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/AddTicket.aspx/UpdateTicket',
            data: ticket,
            dataType: 'application/json', 
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                alert("User has been added successfully.");
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static void UpdateTicket(Ticket ticket)
    {
        HelpDeskManager pp = new HelpDeskManager();
        pp.UpdateTicket(ticket);
    }
```

Comment: hi Dev I can help you . Tell me what is the issue ? any exception or error ? Also can you check first on Network Tab your ajax post request is called or not ?

Comment: it says that the post UpdateTicket is not reached . So I think yu have issue with your public static void UpdateTicket(Ticket ticket) method

Comment: Try "/AddTicket.aspx/UpdateTicket/" instead of "AddTicket.aspx/UpdateTicket" and your second dataType isn't needed

Comment: check the image i attached

Comment: yes i deleted one datatype and changed url also but no result

Comment: Try adding a [HttpPost] attribute to your method.